# Invisible Like-Button

Tags: iframe, facebook-like

I used the Like-Button for months on several websites. The button still works well on www.gartenfit.com and www.aussenanlagenideen.de.

Now, since a couple of weeks I can't see the Like-Button on two of my websites anymore: www.tagstiles.com and www.kitawaldstrasse.de

If I'm logged in on facebook, I can see the grey shadow of the Like-Button on the two websites mentioned above. If I'm not logged in on facebook, I can't see the button.

I created a new iframe-Code for the Like-Button and copied it into a new html-document. The page is blank (no visible Like-Button). I tried in IE, FF and Opera. Nothing. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Unbenanntes Dokument</title>
</head>

<body>
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2Ftagstilescom%2F314372591939008&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=150&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=verdana&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:150px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

What's the reason, that I can't see the Like-Button anymore?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

The same works in jsfiddle.
In fact i can see the like button in the 2 linked sites as well.
Using chrome 19.

As it is on iframe, maybe there is a problem calling the source?

Also its first time I'm seeing an src beginning with "//www.someurl..."
Try removing the // or adding protcol before it.

Comment: @Luke Laser: maybe there is some problem in your server importing from the iframed src? Try checking the javascript console for errors.

Comment: If so, I wouldn't be able to see the buttons on www.gartenfit.com and www.aussenanlagen.de, too. It's the same server...

Comment: Oh alright. I can see it on both websites using both chrome 19 and IE 9. Try refreshing cache. use ctrl+F5 or shift+F5 to refresh without cache. Or try using incognito/private mode once. Do reply whether or not you tried 'em!

Comment: By the way, it's showin the button on  www.kitawaldstrasse.de even if i'm logged in or not, but on www.tagstiles.com if I'm not logged in it shows the up and down scroll buttons in place of 'xxx on FB', but nothing besides the buttons. Works fine if signed in though

Answer (score 0):

I can see the Like button on your site just fine too. Is there a reason why your code has `<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?` as apposed to `<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?` (i.e. the missing protocol `http`)?

Your website doesn't support HTTPS so you might as well add in `http` in the iframe URL.

Comment: I already tried before I posted my question. It doesn't work. On www.kitawaldstrasse.de I built a work-around. You can see the button, but only because it's simple picture linking to the facebook-website.

Comment: On www.tagstiles.com I kept the original iframe code. There is an http: in front.

Comment: I tried jsfidlle. I can see the button there, too. But somehow it doesn't work in the above mentioned browsers. I tried Safari now, too. Nothing.

Comment: Have you tried using the HTML5 version?
`<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>`

Comment: Yes, I also tried to change the DOCTYPE. Same result. 

Just to get one thing sure: You are not logged in on facebook and you can see the blue like-button on www.tagstiles.com, right?!

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Strange. Are you using any geo/age restrictions on your page? Your fan page is unavailable to a logged out user so it's a page setting that is causing the Like button to not appear.

Comment: Ok, I think, you're right. Thanks so far. I tried to change the facebook settings of these two accounts, but I couldn't find an option to make my pages available for logged out users. Am I just blind or is it impossible after I've set up the pages once?

Comment: If there are no restrictions on the page, it should be automatically available to logged out users. I couldn't find any special settings to make it explicitly public.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to the problem, If you set restriction to which country viewers can view your page, then when user is logged out fb can determine which country you viewing the page. Remove country restriction, age restriction then it will work

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem and it ended up being the adblocker plus chrome plugin. When I turned it off for that one site, voila, there was the lost like button. I had to write this here even though this question is two years old in the hopes it might help some other lost soul seeking their button.